# How to select date from calendar using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am newbie to `Selenium webdriver`. I am using `Java` programming language.

My problem is i am not able to call calendar element and select the date inside it.

Here is the link:

https://www.veltra.com/en/asia/malaysia/kuala_lumpur/a/139387

Any help is much appreciated.

```
List<WebElement> allDates=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td"));

        for(WebElement selectDate:allDates)
        {       
            String date=selectDate.getText();

            if(date.equalsIgnoreCase("31"))
            {
                selectDate.click();
                break;
            }

        }
```

What I planned is, after I click "Book Now" button, I want to select `31st July` in the calendar. The date will then display in the text box.

Comment: Instead, why don't you send the date to the element using `SendKeys`?

Comment: Can you help us to navigate to calendar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the date **31** from the calander for the first item you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.veltra.com/en/asia/malaysia/kuala_lumpur/a/139387");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='hltitle clearfix fclear price_note_wrapper']//following::a[2]"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='hltitle clearfix fclear price_note_wrapper']//following::a[starts-with(@id, 'book_now_btn_')][1]//following::table[1]//input[starts-with(@name, 'data')]"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//span[text()='31']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: 31_07_2019]

Comment: What is the need of creating Webdriverwait instance 3 times ?

Comment: @cruisepandey You need to replace the demonstrated figure of `20` with the timespan mentioned in the _Test Specification_ for each individual element as all the 3 _WebDriverWaits_ are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB! WebDriverWait definitely solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The text of the active dates is no just the day, it also contain the price. For example for July 31 the text is `31\nUSD 266.67`.

You can either use `startsWith()`

```
if (date.startsWith("31")) {
    selectDate.click();
    break;
}
```

Or use locator that points to the date itself

```
By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td//span")
```